# Matrix Factorization For Time Series Collaborative Filtering

Tags: deep-learning, recommender-system, matrix-decomposition

I am working with sequential user data, where I am trying to predict the behavior of a user at a given time `user_i_t`

I have historical data for other users, and their behavior over time, and I am wondering if the latent feature generation of matrix factorization works with time series, ie if I know the actions at every step 
`[0, t]` for users `a-c`, and for user `d` I know the actions at steps `[0, s], s<t`, can I use matrix factorization to predict the actions at steps `[s, t]` for user `d` ?

```
u_a| 1 | 4 | 2 | 1
u_b| 1 | 2 | 5 | 3
u_c| 2 | 3 | 4 | 1
u_d| 1 | 4 | - | -

Columns represent time steps [0, 4]
```

Bonus question: If I generate these missing (predicted) values using matrix factorization, and existing features in the matrix are embeddings (say word2vec), can the predicted values be decoded to have meaning, or are they simply machine approximations?